# Sizing of VSTS tab extension content

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I develop a custom tab to present VSTS build results. VSTS hosts the tab content in an `iframe` with `height: 100%`. However one of its ancestors (`div` with class `build-custom-tab`) has fixed height of 400px:

[image: VSTS DOM screenshot]

This means that if my tab content is longer than 400px in height, it's cut. How can I get around this limit? Specifically I would like my extension to use all available space.

There is `VSS.resize` method in the VSTS SDK, but it modifies size of the `iframe` which is not enough.

Complete source code of the extension is available [here](https://github.com/Oriflame/VSTSTestResultExtension).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify height property:

```
 "properties": {
                "name": "Test results [preview]",
                "uri": "static/test-results.html",
                "order": -100,
                "height": 600
            }
```

Comment: Well, what about variable size to fill the browser window?

Comment: What do you mean variable size?

Comment: I want the content of my tab to fill all available space, depending on the window size, like when `height: 100%`. Maybe this could be done by setting the height in the manifest to a large value and then resize the `iframe` dynamically. It's not an elegant solution however.

Comment: Using `"height":"100%"` instead.